# Maintenance oil change

Tags: maintenance, oil-change

Why would a tamper seal be installed when I took my vehicle to a meineke shop for an oil change?  When it says memo on slip & the shop offers free towing, need I now be worried something is wrong with car?   I called & asked why a Tamper Seal was installed & informed that it was placed & if someone else were to touch it other than their shop, their shop could tell.  Does this mean I have to take it back to a meniecke shop for oil changes in the future or something bad will happen to my car? Tha mis for answers in advance.

Comment: It probably just means that if somebody else services your car and breaks the tamper seals, and the car then breaks down, Meineke won't then give you free towing to repair it. That seems fair enough to me. You can get your car serviced anywhere you like.

Comment: So Meineke expects the owner *not to check their own oil*? Wow, I think I'd not be going back to them again.

Comment: I would expect and hope the seal was on the drain plug and/or filter... if on the dipstick then that would make me think of not going back....